# When i start run this tailwind code... he will give me error.... anyone suggest what am i doing?

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

[Error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk7u0.png)

When i start run this tailwind code. He will give me error. Anyone suggest what am I doing?

Comment: You might need to give some more information (share the package.json & postcss.config.js) but it sounds like you don't have the `autoprefixer` package installed with npm

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you share what the contents of your postcss.config.js are?